# removeChild() and addEventListener()

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a Library project using vanilla JS and I can't understand the behaviour of removeChild() and addEventListener() in the code.

```
var myLibrary = [];
var content = document.querySelector(".content");
var nameField = document.createElement("input");
var authorField = document.createElement("input");
var pagesField = document.createElement("input");
var readingStatusField = document.createElement("input");
var submitButton = document.createElement("button");

var form = document.createElement("form");

function Book(name, author, pages, status){
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.status = status
    
}
Book.prototype.info = function(){
    if(this.status === false){
        return console.log(this.name + " " + "by " + this.author + "," + this.pages + " pages, " + "not read yet" )
    }
    else{
        return console.log(this.name + " " + "by " + this.author + "," + this.pages + " pages, "+ "read" )
    }
}



function addBookToLibrary(Book) {
  myLibrary.push(Book);

}






function displayBooks(){
    for(let x = 0; x < myLibrary.length; x++){
        myLibrary[x].info();
    }
}


function createBookForm() {
    
       
    

        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.classList.add("book-form")
        
        
        nameField.classList.add("formfield")
        nameField.setAttribute("type", "text");
        nameField.setAttribute("placeholder", "Name");
        
        
        
        
        authorField.classList.add("formfield")
        authorField.setAttribute("type", "text");
        authorField.setAttribute("placeholder", "Author");
        

        
        
        pagesField.classList.add("formfield")
        pagesField.setAttribute("type", "text");
        pagesField.setAttribute("placeholder", "Pages");
        
    
        
        readingStatusField.classList.add("formfield")
        readingStatusField.setAttribute("type", "text");
        readingStatusField.setAttribute("placeholder", "Reading Status");
        
        
        
        submitButton.innerHTML = "Add"
        submitButton.classList.add("submitButton")
        submitButton.setAttribute("type", "submit");
        submitButton.setAttribute("value", "Submit");
        // submitButton.onclick("")
        
        
            
       
        
        form.appendChild(submitButton);
        form.appendChild(readingStatusField);
        form.appendChild(pagesField);
        form.appendChild(authorField);
        form.appendChild(nameField);
        
        
        
        
        content.appendChild(form);
        
        
    
    
  }
  function getInfoFromForm() {
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            
        let bookName = nameField.value;
        let authorName = authorField.value;
        let noOfPages = pagesField.value;
        let readingStatus = readingStatusField.value;
        let newBook = new Book(bookName, authorName, noOfPages, readingStatus);
        addBookToLibrary(newBook);
        displayBooks();
        nameField.value = "";
        authorField.value = "";
        pagesField.value = "";
        readingStatusField.value = "";
        content.innerHTML = ""
        content.removeChild(form);
    })
 
 
}

  
let addBookButton = document.querySelector(".addBook");
addBookButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let content = document.querySelector(".content")
    createBookForm();
    getInfoFromForm();
    deleteForm();

   
})
```

In createBookForm() function, I create a form and append it to the content div. It worked fine.
In getInfoFromForm() function, I try to get info from the form, and when submit button is clicked I want to create an Book object and store it in the myLibrary[] array.
Here things get out of hand for me.
First of all, the removeChild method doesnt work and doesn't remove the form element from the content.
Second when I try to console.log the books from myLibrary[], at first submit it shows correctly. When I try this second time, it shows the first book, second book THREE TIMES and an empty book.
WHY ISN'T removeChild removing the form element and why is cicking the submit button behaves the way it is behaving.

Comment: Where are you calling `removeChild`?

Comment: in getInfoFromForm() function( to delete the form once the information is gathered and pushed to the library)

Comment: You're creating a new event listener every time you invoke the function `getInfoFromForm`. Move the event listener outside the function